# M2 Admin javascript error "productType.type is undefined" on product save

Tags: admin, error, magento2, javascript

This weird error has been bothering me for a while. Whenever I click Save Product, the please wait gif shows up and keep spinning forever. I looked in the debug console and it says "*productType.type is undefined*" in 3 lines of code:

In `apply-to-type-switcher.js`:

```
if (applyTo.length === 0 || $.inArray(productType.type.current, applyTo) !== -1)...
```

In `downloadable-type-handler.js`:

```
if (productType.type.current === 'downloadable') {
```

In `apply-to-type-switcher.js`:

```
if (applyTo.length === 0 || $.inArray(productType.type.current, applyTo) !== -1)...
```

Those are apparently javascript errors, but I don't really know what causes this. If there's any further info needed about my project, please ask.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem, what I did is run command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Clear cache and problem fixed.

Hope this helps